FFMPEG mp3 Encryption
I have been trying to make encrypted mp3 audio like this:
ffmpeg -i input.mp3  -acodec copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 4fac3c5fef15380e158040eef78d5d67 -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 output.mp3
... and it doesn't work: the process looks like encryption is happening, but the output file is not encrypted. Could you please advise how it is possible to encrypt the mp3 audio file with ffmpeg?
Thank you!

Encrypting an MP3 file directly using FFmpeg might not work as expected because FFmpeg's encryption options are typically used for formats and containers that support encryption, such as MP4. The MP3 format itself does not natively support encryption.
However, you can encrypt an MP3 file using external tools. One common method is to use OpenSSL to encrypt the file after it has been created. Here’s how you can do it:
Using OpenSSL for Encryption

Encrypt the MP3 File:
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in input.mp3 -out output.mp3.enc -pass pass:yourpassword


-aes-256-cbc: Specifies the AES encryption method with a 256-bit key in CBC mode.
-salt: Adds a salt to the encryption for security.
-in input.mp3: Specifies the input file.
-out output.mp3.enc: Specifies the output file.
-pass pass:yourpassword: Specifies the password for encryption.


Decrypt the MP3 File:
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in output.mp3.enc -out decrypted.mp3 -pass pass:yourpassword


-d: Specifies decryption mode.
-in output.mp3.enc: Specifies the encrypted input file.
-out decrypted.mp3: Specifies the decrypted output file.
-pass pass:yourpassword: Specifies the password used during encryption.



Encrypting with FFmpeg using MP4 Container
If you specifically need to use FFmpeg, consider wrapping the MP3 in an MP4 container and then applying encryption. Here’s how:

Convert MP3 to MP4:
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a copy -f mp4 intermediate.mp4


Encrypt the MP4 File:
ffmpeg -i intermediate.mp4 -c:a copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 4fac3c5fef15380e158040eef78d5d67 -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 encrypted.mp4


Extract MP3 (optional):
If you need the MP3 file separately, you can decrypt and extract it:
ffmpeg -decryption_key 4fac3c5fef15380e158040eef78d5d67 -i encrypted.mp4 -c:a copy decrypted.mp3



This approach leverages FFmpeg’s encryption capabilities with formats that support it, such as MP4, and then optionally extracts the audio content. For direct MP3 encryption, using OpenSSL is a straightforward method.

Thank you very much! That is very helpful!
